# DateTime datatype in BigQuery

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery

I have a partitioned table where one of the column is of type DateTime and the table is partitioned on same column.  According to spark-bigquery documentation, the corresponding Spark SQL type is of String type.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector

I tried doing the same but I am getting datatype mismatch issue.

**Code Snippet:**

```
ZonedDateTime nowPST = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(), TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST").toZoneId());
        df = df.withColumn("createdDate", lit(nowPST.toLocalDateTime().toString()));
```

**Error:**

```
Caused by: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Failed to load to <PROJECT_ID>:<DATASET_NAME>.<TABLE_NAME> in job JobId{project=<PROJECT_ID>, job=<JOB_ID>, location=US}. BigQuery error was Provided Schema does not match Table <PROJECT_ID>:<DATASET_NAME>.<TABLE_NAME>. Field createdDate has changed type from DATETIME to STRING
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryWriteHelper.loadDataToBigQuery(BigQueryWriteHelper.scala:156)
        at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryWriteHelper.writeDataFrameToBigQuery(BigQueryWriteHelper.scala:89)
        ... 36 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Spark has no support for `DateTime`, the BigQuery connector does not support writing `DateTime` - there is no equivalent Spark data type that can be used. We are exploring ways to augment the DataFrame's metadata in order to support the types which are supported by BigQuery and not by Spark (`DateTime`, `Time`, `Geography`).

At the moment please have this field as String, and have the conversion on the BigQuery side.

Comment: Hi @David, if we want to use this column as partitioned column and make the column in spark as String, then how will I be able to use this column as BigQuery doesn't support partitioning on String Column.
Can you please throw some light on conversion at BigQuery Side?

Comment: Hi @David, 
basically the major problem is we are inserting data into timestamp column in PST, but BigQuery automatically appending UTC to it, which is quite confusing for the end user

Comment: Hi @arunkindra sorry, I guess my comment wasn't sent. I meant for inserting the data as String into a temporary table,and then run an `INSERT INTO partitioned_table SELECT ...` on BigQuery

Answer (score -1):

I am running into this issue now as well with both geography https://community.databricks.com/s/question/0D58Y000099mPyDSAU/does-databricks-support-writing-geographygeometry-data-into-bigquery

And for Datetime types. The only way I could get the table from databricks to BigQuery (without creating a temporary table and Inserting the data as this would still be costly due to the size of the table) was to write the table out to a CSV into a GCS Bucket

```
results_df.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").save("gs://<bucket-name>/ancillary_test")
```

And then load the data from the bucket to the table in BigQuery specifying the schema

```
LOAD DATA INTO <dataset>.<tablename>(
    PRICENODEID INTEGER,
    ISONAME STRING,
    PRICENODENAME STRING,
    MARKETTYPE STRING,
    GMTDATETIME TIMESTAMP,
    TIMEZONE STRING,
    LOCALDATETIME DATETIME,
    ANCILLARY STRING,
    PRICE FLOAT64,
    CHANGE_DATE TIMESTAMP
)
FROM FILES (
  format = 'CSV',
  uris = ['gs://<bucket-name>/ancillary_test/*.csv']
    );
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33669179)